# What does "contract a trace" mean?

Tags: meaning

> It is hardly possible for people to live for so many years as slaves
>   in everyday contact with fascists and fascism without becoming
>   somewhat twisted, without **contracting a trace** of that dry rot
>   unwittingly and unwillingly.

I know the meaning of the words invidually include the meaning of [dry rot](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dry-rot).  I think the meaning of [contract](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/contract) is  "to catch or become ill with a disease" but I'm not sure.

Could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text is:

> The years of imprisonment had yet another paradoxical effect. Although
>   we continually hoped for freedom, our concept of freedom had changed.
>   Shut up behind barbed wire, robbed of all rights including the right
>   to live, we had stopped regarding freedom as something natural and
>   self-evident. Gradually, the idea of freedom as birthright became
>   blurred. By the end of their time in the camps, many prisoners came to
>   accept the view that freedom is something that has to be earned and
>   fought for, a privilege that is awarded, like a medal. It is hardly
>   possible for people to live for so many years as slaves in everyday
>   contact with fascists and fascism without becoming somewhat twisted,
>   without **contracting a trace of that dry rot** unwittingly and
>   unwillingly. Usually, the reasoning went something like this: if, for
>   the purpose of building a new society, it is necessary to give up my
>   freedom for a time, to subsume something I cherish to a cause in which
>   I strongly believe, that is a sacrifice I am willing to make. In any
>   case, we are a lost generation. We all might have died uselessly in
>   the camps. Since we did survive, we want to dedicate what is left of
>   our lives to the future. This streak of martyrdom was stronger than
>   was generally understood. People felt chosen by destiny to sacrifice
>   themselves, a feeling that was reinforced by a strong sense of guilt
>   that characterized many who had survived the camps. Why was I alive
>   and not my father, my mother, my friend? I owed them something. They
>   had died in place of me. For their sake I had to build a world in
>   which this could never happen again. This was where the misconception
>   lay: in the idea that Communism was the one system under which it
>   could never happen again. Of course we knew about the Communism of the
>   thirties in the Soviet Union, but that was an era of cruelty that had
>   ended long ago, the kind of crisis out of which all great change is
>   born. Who, today, would condemn democracy for the Terror of the
>   Jacobins after the French Revolution?

*Under a Cruel Star*, A Life in Prague 1941-1968 by  Heda Margolius Kovály

Translated  by  Helen Epstein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, here are the relevant definitions...

> **contract** *- to catch or become ill with a disease* [<sub>(Source)</sub>](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/contract)
>
> **trace** *- a very slight amount* [<sub>(Source)</sub>](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trace)
>
> **dry rot** *- a disease caused by a fungus that destroys wood in houses, boats, etc.* [<sub>(Source)</sub>](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dry-rot)
>
> *[People cannot live this way] without contracting a trace of [that disease]*

I'd say there's some weakness in the translation here, because ***that*** dry rot doesn't seem to refer back to any specific antecedent (which would normally be expected). So far as I can see, it's up to the reader to construct a suitable "preceding noun" to serve as the target of ***that*** (usually we'd expect the relevant noun phrase to be explicitly provided earlier in the text).

Logically, "that dry rot" is probably intended to refer to the previously-mentioned ***acceptance*** [of the idea that freedom isn't a right, it has to be earned]. But it's not really very clearly expressed.

---

TL;DR: It's a stylised way of saying...

> *Anyone who lives like this [as a prisoner] will probably **come to think** [that rights must be fought for]*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure that "that dry rot" does not apply to fascism. That is, even though one is a prisoner as a result of an objectionable ideology, one is never immune from imbibing the ideas of that ideology by osmosis.

Answer (score -1):

Both *twisted* and *dry-rot* are close in what they allude to in relation to people who hadn't cracked under fascism and thus managed to preserve their entity.

And, accordingly, I would proffer this interpretation"...without becoming somewhat *perverted (evil, corrupt)* without contracting a trace of that *moral degeneration (depravity, decay)* unwittingly and unwillingly.

Comment: Nah. The writer isn't claiming long-term prisoners actually *become* "morally degenerate" themselves. He's saying they become "infected" by ***despair*** (they lose their idealism, and no longer believe that freedom is an inalienable birthright). That's to say, people who have ***lost hope*** (in society, their fellow man, human rights) aren't so much "degenerate" as "diseased".